# Ruby: replace a given URL in an HTML string

Tags: ruby, regex

In Ruby, I want to replace a given URL in an HTML string.
Here is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
escaped_url = url.gsub(/\//,"\/").gsub(/\./,"\.").gsub(/\?/,"\?")
path_regexp = Regexp.new(escaped_url)
html.gsub!(path_regexp, new_url)
```

Note: `url` is actually a Google Chart request URL I wrote, which will not have more special characters than `/?|.=%:`

Comment: First here's a tip: gsub returns the substituted text, gsub! changes your variable and returns nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) method can take a string or a Regexp as its first argument, same goes for [`gsub!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub-21). For example:

```
>> 'here is some ..text.. xxtextxx'.gsub('..text..', 'pancakes')
=> "here is some pancakes xxtextxx"
```

So you don't need to bother with a regex or escaping at all, just do a straight string replacement:

```
html.gsub!(url, new_url)
```

Or better, use an HTML parser to find the particular node you're looking for and do a simple attribute assignment.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
path_regexp = Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(url))
```